# Concurrency on Stateless Bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, ejb-3.1, glassfish-4

I have two session bean:

- A stateless session Bean called AuctionFrontEnd.
- A singleton session Bean called StateAuctionFrontEnd

In the StateAuctionFrontAnd there is a HashMap and the methods for put and remove element from HashMap. The Concurrency is handled by @Lock(WRITE)  and @Lock(WRITE) annotations.

The AuctionFrontEnd Bean implements the business logic methods that  call the methods in the StateAuctionFrontEnd.

An example method in the AuctionFrontAnd is the follower(pseudo-code):

```
public void removeValue(int key){
  if(stateAuctionFronEnd.getHashMap().containsKey(key))
     stateAuctionFronEnd.getHashMap().remove(key);
}
```

If there are two clients who want to eliminate the same element, an exception can be triggered.
Both call the delete method , and both come in 'if'.
One removes the element and the other launches an exception.

I have the same problem in the other business methods.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Use a concurrent data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get `stateAuctionFronEnd.getHashMap()` you leave the lock of the EJB and modify concurrently the map.

Switching to a concurrent data structure wouldn't help, because the `if` statement and the `delete` are both outside of the synchronized block of the EJB.

You should move the logic completely to the Singleton bean and encapsulate the access to the hashmap, like:

```
@Lock(WRITE)
public void removeValue(int key){
     if(stateAuctionFronEnd.getHashMap().containsKey(key))
          stateAuctionFronEnd.getHashMap().remove(key);
}
```

Alternatively you could also synchronize the called code

Comment: But remember, when you use manual synchronization you should use `@ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN)` type on your singleton class.

Comment: It is a solution! Otherwise if I were using the Transaction API to ensure the ' atomicity of a sequence of operations ?

Comment: @slwk yes, but i meant the manual synchronization in the stateless bean. 

using transactions should work and would fall into "manual synchronizing" category, but be careful not to lock for long